# How do I create an instance of the Array type with a given ElementType?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, serialization, reflection

How do I create a type object that represents the type of an array with a given element type?

```
Type t = MakeArrayType(elementType);  // How?
```

Such that

```
Assert(t.GetElementType() == elementType);
```

I can create a dummy *instance* of my requested array and then get the type from there. But I wonder if there is a way to get the type without creating the instance first?

```
object myArrayInstance = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, 0);
Type t = myArrayInstance.GetType();   // This is the desired type.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `t` refers to a `Type`, then `t.GetType()` will obviously be `typeof(Type)` or a subtype - not `typeof(Array)`.

However, I suspect you want [`Type.MakeArrayType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc2e4ft8.aspx):

```
Type arrayType = elementType.MakeArrayType();
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I edited the question too (t.GetType() -> just t). I don't know why I didn't think of going "backwards" rather than starting at typeof(Array).

Comment: @Anders: You still won't get `t == typeof(Array)` - if that worked, you could just use `typeof(Array)` to start with :) You'll get a `t` which is assignment-compatible with `Array` though.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Just out of curiosity (I'll change the question so it mathes the answer later), how would a proper assert in the question look really? Simply Assert(t.IsArray()) perhaps? or did that assert not help the question at all :) ?

Comment: `t.IsArray` would work, yes. Or `typeof(Array).IsAssignableFrom(t)`